# Unique "reference" for form response?

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-forms

I just created a Google form for online enquiries for my business. I set it up so that it sends an email to the person who submits the form using the "FormEmailer" script but my question is, is there a way I can give that person or more specifically that FormEmailer generated email a unique "Reference" number at the time of submission?

Thanks in advance.

Dan

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, if you are willing to do some coding on your own.

You may want to look at the recently launched [Form Notification add-on for Google Forms](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/form-notifications/bbpdeojefjfhaelgljjcadpcckdfcdod), which also sends emails to people who respond to a form. This add-on is meant to be a code sample, and you can find the [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-form-notifications-addon), and [a quickstart about it in the Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/forms-add-on).

To do what you are asking, you would just need to copy the code and add another "Reference number" field to the [RespondentNotification template](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-form-notifications-addon/blob/master/RespondentNotification.html), and then modify the [sendRespondentNotification() function](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-form-notifications-addon/blob/master/Code.gs#L267) accordingly.  Alternatively, you can just insert the reference number into the email subject in that function.

Note that this add-on has some limitations: the number of emails sent out (like all of Apps Script) are subject to quota limits. In addition, the add-on isn't really meant used for forms with multiple collaborators/editors. However, [Form Notifications](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/form-notifications/bbpdeojefjfhaelgljjcadpcckdfcdod) should give you a good idea of how to write scripts that respond well to form submissions.

Comment: This is confusing. How can I do this step by step? I copied github sources to relevant gs and html pages. How can I now add the reference number in sheet to the respondent email? @Ryan Roth