# How to add a unique Reference ID to Google form respondent email

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, google-forms

I am using a Google form that collects data and upon submission it needs to show a unique reference ID to the person who submits data. The responses spreadsheet generates the unique ID however and I want to add that to the respondent email.

I used Google form notifications add-on and could enable sending out a mail to the respondent. The thing is how can I add the generated ID or the time stamp of the response to the email? Check the image below.

[image]

I am new to this and I found a similar question here but I am confused how to use it to accomplish this work. 
[Unique "reference" for form response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350199/unique-reference-for-form-response)

Earlier there was a script gallery that we can search and add script add-ons and could find the FormMailer add-on that does this without any hassle upon the addition of a new record to the spreadsheet. But that feature is no longer there and a script editor is present and I am confused with this new method. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-o6JCQcLsBo

Please help me to do this.

Comment: The add-on appears to do what you need, you just need to learn the inclusion syntax for form fields: http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-docs-email-form/20884/. I would recommend using both the timestamp and the submission number as your unique ID. I use timestamp.getTime() to generate a unique ID (it returns the timestamp in millisecond value). Timestamp only goes to a second and you may, however unlikely, end up with duplicates.